# CAML Query Return All Tasks by Current User

Tags: sharepoint, caml

I am trying to query all Tasks throughout my site collection using the following where clause in my CAML Query.  From what I can tell this code is exactly as specified in this presumably reliable [blog entry](http://waelmohamed.wordpress.com/2013/06/10/get-tasks-assigned-to-user-or-to-current-user-groups-in-sharepoint-using-caml-query/).  Anyone know why it would not work?
Thanks for reading

My code won't even execute as it complains about my CAML Query

```
"<Where>" +

     "<And>" +
         "<BeginsWith>" +
              "<FieldRef Name=\"ContentTypeId\" />" +
              "<Value Type=\"ContentTypeId\">0x0108009D937E40833C472CBC11D246C635B662</Value>" +
         "</BeginsWith>" +

          "<Eq>" +
               "<FieldRef Name=\"TaskStatus\" />" +
               "<Value Type=\"Text\">Completed</Value>" +
          "</Eq>" +


          "<Eq>" +
                "<FieldRef Name=\"AssignedTo\" />" +
                 "<Value Type=\"Lookup\">" + id + "</Value>" +
          "</Eq>" +

          "</And>" +

          "</Where>" +

            "<OrderBy>" +
                 "<FieldRef Name=\"Title\"/>" +
            "</OrderBy>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the above answer. Since there are multiple And elements here, and any And element supports only 2 conjuncts, nested And elements must be used to conjoin multiple conditions. If you are using the default Task List in SharePoint, try the following CAML Query-

```
<Query>
    <Where>
        <And>
            <BeginsWith>
                <FieldRef Name="ContentTypeId" />
                <Value Type="Counter">0x0108009D937E40833C472CBC11D246C635B662</Value>
            </BeginsWith>
            <And>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name="TaskStatus" />
                    <Value Type="Choice">Completed</Value>
                </Eq>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo" />
                    <Value Type="UserMulti">id</Value>
                </Eq>
            </And>
        </And>
    </Where>
    <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="Title" Ascending="False" />
    </OrderBy>
</Query>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple conditions in the `And` element. The `And` elements supports only two conditions as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sharepoint/ms196939.aspx). Rewrite the query using multiple nested `And` elements containing only two conditions or other `And` elements.